# Unable to resolve dependency: dashing (= 1.3.1) requires sass (>= 0) on RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, suse, dashing

Error while trying to Install Dashing using Ruby Gems on SUSE linux....

```
sudo gem install -V dashing --source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependency: dashing (= 1.3.1) requires sass (>= 0)
spothi # sudo gem install -V dashing
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependency: dashing (= 1.3.1) requires sass (>= 0)
spothi # sudo gem install  dashing
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependency: dashing (= 1.3.1) requires sass (>= 0)
spothi # sudo gem install dashing-1.0.5.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependency: dashing (= 1.0.5) requires sass (>= 0)
```

Please let me know, how to resolve as I already tried changing source from https to http as well.

Comment: Just install sass gem:)

Comment: Then I am getting this error :    sudo gem install sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: It seems like problem about accessing rubygems. Try install gems with github source code. 'gem install sass -l https://github.com/nex3/sass'.

Comment: gem install sass -l github.com/nex3/sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'github.com/nex3/sass' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: gem install sass --source http://github.com/nex3/sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
          Unable to download data from http://github.com/nex3/sass/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://github.com/nex3/sass/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Answer (score 1):

t was mainly due to company's proxy and I have tried

gem install -p http:proxy:port dashing

it workeId